# The find function does not work in Ubuntu14.04

Tags: 14.04

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my PC a couple of days ago.
Frankly speaking, it is a very great OS with high performance.
But what brings me trouble is the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> function does not work in every application(such as chrome, gedit).
I am not sure whether this problem is caused by some bug of this OS or by myself resulted from unsuitable settings.

Comment: Shortcuts are set by the applications so you need to change the shortcuts there if you want them to be different.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this will answer your question but should push you along the right lines,

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KeyboardShortcuts

Here you will find a list of the existing short cuts and an example of how to make your own!

thanks,

Mathew

Comment: Don`t just post links, edit the relevant parts in your answer.